# Cross Platform MIDI library supporting iOS CoreMIDI

Tags: c++, ipad, ios, midi, coremidi

I'm looking for a cross-platform C or C++ MIDI library. Just to send/receive MIDI note events, control codes and timing, not to generate sound.

The main target is iOS/iPad so it has to support CoreMIDI on iOS, which I know is fairly recent. I can use CoreMidi directly but if there's something lightweight out there it would be nice to use something portable so I could easily port the project to PC's.

Failing that, please mention if there's a good, lightweight one that's open source it might be easier for me to add CoreMIDI support than to roll my own.

Clarification: I'm looking for something similar to [MidiIO](http://midiio.sapp.org/) or [PortMIDI](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/portmedia/wiki/portmidi) that has good iOS support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [RtMidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/).

It provides a cross-platform API for realtime MIDI input/output, and makes use of the native API's for each platform (winmm, ALSA, CoreMidi).

I haven't used it with CoreAudio/CoreMidi, but it's worked flawlessly for me on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know MIDI thing in iOS dev. To my understanding, sending/receiving MIDI note events to/from MIDI devices should be a pure OS API problem. And parsing/generating MIDI messages is about MIDI spec. I suppose neither leads to a need of a library.

Comment: See the clarification above. I can certainly use CoreMIDI directly (and it looks increasing like that's my only option) but if there were an established wrapper library it would make it easier to port it to Windows or Linux eventually.